# Reference to the video element

Tags: javascript, video.js

Using the built code from the cdn, from inside a plugin, is there an easy way to get the player object or video element without using `this.F` (I see this being quite risky if things are changed in the build.)

Non-built version I can easily use `this.tag` or `this.player()` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.el()` will return the container div. `this.el().querySelector("video")` should get you the video element